# GIT Xcode - change origin

Tags: xcode, git

How can i change the origin url in the GIT Repository. I dont want to add a new repo. I want to change the old one.Please help me. I find option to add new one but not change the existing one.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think you can do that from XCode4, much like many other things.

Do `git remote set-url origin <newurl>` like @Dan Ray suggests, or go to .git/config and edit the url to the new one.

And one piece of advice, Git is enjoyed through the command line, so where the IDE/ GUI doesn't work, be happy to work from the command line.

Comment: I am getting authentication error, while using GIT with XCODE. THe Username and Password is correct. Still it gives me errors.

Answer (score 5):

```
# git remote set-url origin <newurl>
```

If your question is how to do this from within Xcode, then I don't know. This is how you do it in *git*. Whatever Xcode would do would really be doing this.

Comment: my question is doing this using XCODE 4.