# Change Git Repository Of Existing Xcode Project

Tags: xcode, git, github, git-clone

I cloned an abandoned repository from Github, and now I want to be able to upload my changes to a private repo so that a few other people can work on the changes with me. Unfortunately, since I cloned it instead of making a fork, so Xcode is trying to make the commits to the original repo. Is there a way to change what repo the commits are being made to? If there is, would there be a way to change it to a repo on another website (Bit Bucket)?

I fully intend to make the repo public once the changes are complete.

Comment: Take a look at: git remote add myremote /path/to/other/repo

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As mentioned in "[Git XCode - change `origin`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5952591/6309)", you simply can change the remote `origin` url, using [`git remote set-url`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) (or in your case, rename+add).

```
git remote rename origin upstream
git remote add origin /url/of/private/repo
```

(with the XCode GUI, you could [remove, then add again, the remote `origin`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9776401/6309))

If that private repo is empty, you can push to the full history of your cloned repo.

By renaming '`origin`' to '`upstream`', you keep the possibility to fetch from the original repo, while pushing to your new `origin` target repo.

Answer (score 26):

You can do it through UI

Select Source Control Navigator from the left pane

There you can find your current remote repo under the Remotes Folder,

[image: select Current Remote]

then delete the existing repo:

[image: Delete Existing Repo]

Now You can add Your Existing Remote

[image: Add New Remote]

Enter Remote URL

[image: Enter Git Remote URL]