# Remote on Git via SSH works differently in the Shell and Xcode

Tags: xcode, git, shell, git-remote

I have set remote using `git remote set-url` but if it includes username, git works fine on terminal and doesn't work in Xcode. If url was set without username, it works only in Xcode, but doesn't work in terminal.

The error showing in the shell without username is `ERROR: Repository not found.`

The Xcode error with included username is `The remote repository could not be accessed` and username in dialog box is `git` without ability to change

I did not change `~/.ssh/config` after OS update. user.name and user.email are set for --local only, no changes here as well.

```
$ git remote set-url origin git@github.com-UserName:repo/project-name.git
//Remote commands work only in Shell

$ git remote set-url origin git@github.com:repo/project-name.git
//Remote commands work only in Xcode
```

Where is the problem, how can I fix this issue and get it working in both Xcode and the shell?

PS: Yesterday I had only one of my repos working in both Xcode and shell when set url without username *(other repos was working as described only either in terminal or xcode)*, but after minor Mac OS update *(just 12.2->12.2.1)* it works the described way also now like others. Have no idea what additionally was set but know it's possible to get working both Xcode and Terminal at least.

[image]

**UPD:** If I change `Host` from `github.com-UserName` to `github.com` I am losing ability to use both repos simultaneously in Terminal because only one repo for added ssh keys works.

```
Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github-User-1

Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github-User-2

//Terminal:
$ ssh-add --apple-use-keychain ~/.ssh/UserName-1
$ ssh-add --apple-use-keychain ~/.ssh/UserName-2 //Only repo with this one will work, another will show `ERROR: Repository not found` as both hosts are same.
```

**UPD 2:** Looks like Xcode is just ignoring ~/.ssh/config file and just using set remote url as is, not replacing Host name with the actual url.

Answer (score 0):

The URL `git@github.com-UserName` can only work if you have a `~/.ssh/config` file with a `Host github.com-UserName` entry in it, which reference the right private key to use (the same private key that XCode has in its settings)

Simply rename that `Host` entry to `Host github.com`, and the `git@github.com:user1/project-name.git` should work in command line (as well as with XCode)

---

If you have more than one repository for the *same* user, you don't need to add anything to your `~/.ssh/config` file.

```
git@github.com:user1/project-name.git
git@github.com:user1/project2-name.git
git@github.com:user1/project3-name.git
...
```

---

If you have more than one user, make sure the `Host` entry is different than the first in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host gh1
  Hostname github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gh1

Host gh2
  Hostname github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gh2
```

This supposes you have generated two SSH keys, one named `gh1`, with `gh1.pub` added to user1, and one named `gh2`, with `gh2.pub` added to user2.

```
ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/gh1 -t rsa -P ""
ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/gh2 -t rsa -P ""
```

Finally, use for the repo1 owned by user1

```
git clone gh1:user1/repo1
# or, for an existing repo1 clone
cd /path/to/local/repo1
git remote set-url origin gh1:user1/repo1
```

And for repo2, owned by user2

```
git clone gh2:user1/repo2
```

Comment: Hi VonC. Had to remove "Solution mark" from your answer.
Your method worked until I've added one more ssh and using second repo now.
I have `~/.ssh/config` and inside I have 2 entries and when I do `ssh-add` only last works. I can add ssh for User-1, then User-2 and only second repo works, another one show an `ERROR: Repository not found`
So, solution doesn't work for multiple repos

`Host github.com`
`    HostName github.com`
`    User git`
`    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github-User-1`

`Host github.com`
`    HostName github.com`
`    User git`
`    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github-User-2`

Comment: @bodich No problem. I have edited the answer to address your new use case.

Comment: Your update is actually my start point from the question. It works for terminal but doesn't work in Xcode. Xcode shows me the error (see screenshot in the main question)

Comment: @bodich you would need to update the URL IN Xcode as well.

Comment: How do you mean to update URL in Xcode?

Comment: @bodich the URL must be `gh1:...` or `gh2:...`, not `git@github.com:...`. For updating the URL in XCode: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58412707/6309

Comment: Yes, I understand, I make url like `gh1:...` or `gh2:...` and it works in Terminal. But Xcode takes git parameters from .git folder in the project, how can I cahnge it in Xcode? Changing in Xcode is absolutely the same as I'd change it in Terminal. Once I'll chenge in Xcode it will affect origin in Terminal and vice versa. Or maybe I understand how git works incorrect and Xcode takes git data not from the same .git folder? Once I make commit in Xcode I see it in Terminal as it's the same thing, Xcode is only GUI over the git here, same as for origin...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243786/discussion-between-vonc-and-bodich).