# Xcode request signin into github with token and ignores my .ssh keys to do a push

Tags: xcode, github, ssh-keys

I have a `.ssh` folder with my `RSA` keys, private and public, but when I try to do push in `Xcode`, it ask me to login in `github` and to get a token access id.

Why is `Xcode` ignoring my `.ssh` folder keys? How to configure it to use the `.ssh` folder keys?

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same situation. I've already checked the remote URLs, and this happens with all the SSH URL types I've tried (git@github.com:user/repo, git@github.com:user/repo.git, ssh://git@github.com/user/repo, and ssh://git@github.com/user/repo.git).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this using some information from https://gist.github.com/brennanMKE/8e09593ca4064deab59da807077d8f53. Specifically, the step:

> Add the key to the Keychain with this command.
>
> `ssh-add --apple-use-keychain ~/.ssh/id_github`

Replace `~/.ssh/id_github` with the path to your SSH key (in my case, `~/.ssh/id_rsa`), enter your passphrase when prompted, and Xcode should start recognizing the key.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check the remote URL you are using. (you can [see it in XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58412707/6309))

Asking for a GitHUb login and token suggests you are using an HTTPS one.

Only an SSH URL (`git@github.com:<user>/<repo>`) would make sue of your SSH folder content.